# Object getting stuck in the floor

Tags: javascript, processing

Ok some I'm making a drag and drop program using PJS on Khan Academy and here is my code:

```
/*    Just a simple drag and drop program    */ 

// TODO: 
// * Add realistic bouncing
// * Add particles when bouncing

// Changeable variables
var testShapeWidth = 45;
var testShapeHeight = 45;
var testShapeX = 200;
var testShapeY = 200;
var gravityStrength = 0.8;


// Unchangeable variables
var onGround = false;
var mouseDown = false;

var round2 = function (num) {
    num = num / 2;
    num = round(num);
    num *= 2;
    return num;
};

var checkIfClicked = function(x, y, w, h) {
    var mx = mouseX;
    var my = mouseY;
    
    var rightSide = x + w;
    var bottomSide = y + h;
    
    if (mx > x && mx < rightSide && my > y && my < bottomSide) {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
};

var draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    fill(0);
    rect(testShapeX, testShapeY, testShapeWidth, testShapeHeight);
    
    testShapeY = round2(testShapeY);
    
    // Check if on the ground or not and update the onGround variable
    if (testShapeY + testShapeHeight < 400) { // If the y coorordinate of the bottom edge of the rectangle is less than 400...
        onGround = false; // The rectangle is not on the ground
    } else if (testShapeY + testShapeHeight >= 400) { // If the y coorordinate of the bottom edge of the rectangle is greater than or equal to 400...
        gravityStrength = round2(gravityStrength * -1) / 2;
    }
    
    if (!onGround && !mouseDown) {
        testShapeY += gravityStrength;
        gravityStrength += 0.2;
    }
    
    if (mouseDown) {
        testShapeX = mouseX - testShapeWidth / 2;
        testShapeY = mouseY - testShapeHeight / 2;
        gravityStrength = 0;
    }
};

var mousePressed = function() {
    if (checkIfClicked(testShapeX, testShapeY, testShapeWidth, testShapeHeight)) {
        mouseDown = true;
    }
};
var mouseReleased = function() {
    mouseDown = false;
};
```

I just added bouncing by replacing these lines:

```
else if (testShapeY + testShapeHeight >= 400) { // If the y coorordinate of the bottom edge of the rectangle is greater than or equal to 400...
        testShapeY = 400 - testShapeHeight;
        gravityStrength = 0;
}
```

with this:

```
else if (testShapeY + testShapeHeight >= 400) { // If the y coorordinate of the bottom edge of the rectangle is greater than or equal to 400...
        gravityStrength = round2(gravityStrength * -1) / 2;
}
```

but now sometimes the rectangle gets stuck in the floor. Here is an example: [image: Example Video]

At first I thought it had something to do with even and odd numbers, which is why I added the round2 function (which rounds to the nearest 2) to no avail. I was hoping that the stackoverflow community can help me solve this issue, as I can not. You'll find the link to my project [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/drag-and-drop-bounce-test/4522564242587648).

Comment: Your code is huge. Chances are that nobody will even bother reading all that. Distill your problem to a smaller one, remove unnecessary code that does not contribute to the problem, and your chances of getting help will dramatically increase

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want it to fall to the floor but bounce a bit when it hits?

Comment: @Dominic My problem is that sometimes instead of bouncing it gets stuck in the floor and won't bounce, as you can see on the gif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a lucky man, because I don't have to sift through all this code to know what's the issue (or else I would have helped someone else tonight, really, this is way too much code). Your problem is math. Your solution is easy.

---

### The problem

Here's what's going on: when the object is low enough to go through the floor, you invert and divide by 2 `gravityStrength`. This is the exact place where things go wrong.

If the object falls more pixels than `gravityStrength / 2` under the ground level, it cannot go up again, as it's position when you add the new `gravityStrength` will still be under the ground. Then it will revert it's direction and half `gravityStrength` again, making sure that it won't budge from this spot ever again (unless you move it by hand). It's definitively stuck.

### The solution

Change this:

```
} else if (testShapeY + testShapeHeight >= 400) { // If the y coorordinate of the bottom edge of the rectangle is greater than or equal to 400...
    gravityStrength = round2(gravityStrength * -1) / 2;
}
```

for this:

```
} else if (testShapeY + testShapeHeight >= 400) { // If the y coorordinate of the bottom edge of the rectangle is greater than or equal to 400...
    testShapeY = 400; // now any speed will bounce. Lower this number to make sure that the object will "get stuck" after a while if otherwise it bounces forever
    gravityStrength = round2(gravityStrength * -1) / 2;
}
```

The idea here being that your algorithm will keep working the same but won't let the object fall low enough to be too low for `gravityStrength` to bring it back bouncing. Alternatively, you could move the `testShapeY = 400;` one line lower and base the `testShapeY` variable on the new `gravityStrength`. That would be pretty nice.

Have fun!